# How to replace content in file using command

Tags: xml, powershell, command-line, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I need to replace the string into a file using PowerShell command.

Inside a file there are XML elements and I need to replace a particular element  `<version>1.0.0.0</version>` with another string `<version>3.0.0.0</version>`.

For normal string I could write like below:

```bsh
(Get-Content "D:\data.text").replace('1.0.0', '3.0.0') | Set-Content D:\data.text
```

How to do expression or pattern which could replace the content between `<version></version>` element.

---

EDIT:

Content of file is below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
  <metadata>
    <id>C:\BuildAgent_SpiderWeb\work\52d106957b762949   \buildoutput\LatestPublished</id>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <authors>sonidha-a</authors>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Need: To replace the content between `ID` element and `Version` element.

Comment: If this is XML I'd recommend using PowerShell's excellent XML editor: `[xml]$data = Get-Content "D:\Data.Text"; $data.x.y.z.Version = "3.0.0.0"`

Comment: If you'd rather use Replace please post a sample of your file including the version (so we can see if it's same line or if there are any surprises)

Comment: I have added details above. Please provide me getcontent command which could replace the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do string replacements on XML data. Ever. Rainbow unicorns will die if you do.

Instead, use PowerShell's XML parser, as @Deadly-Bagel already suggested:

```bsh
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml'
$xml.package.metadata.version = '3.0.0.0'
$xml.Save('C:\path\to\output.xml')
```

Comment: How to execute these separate multiple lines command into powerscript ? I am new bit.

Comment: Copy/paste it into the PowerShell console or a PowerShell script.

Comment: also, I need to add `<files>
    <file src="Published\**\**" target="content\" />
   </files>` content into just below the `</metadata>` end element. can you please tell me how to do that.

Comment: Please do not move the target. If you have a new question: post a new question.